# Spring mvc webservice : input control "validator"

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, jackson

Here is an example of my webservice:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value="{width}/{height}/{limit}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ThumbnailResponse createThumbnails(@PathVariable int width, @PathVariable int height, @PathVariable int limit) {
    List<String> list = thumbnailService.processImages(width,height,limit);
    return new ThumbnailResponse(list.size(),list);
}
```

What I want to do is to answer a 400 BAD REQUEST to the user if the value of width or height is less than 10.

I need a kind of "REST Validator" before sending the response to the user. How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I would follow is based on [Spring MVC exception handling](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

What it means in practice is that:

1. You make a custom exception
2. Change your controller method accordingly
3. Catch the exception in your exception handler, and set the proper status and message

In terms of code it would mean

```
public class HeightNotAllowedException extends Exception {
}
```

Change in the controller

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value="{width}/{height}/{limit}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ThumbnailResponse createThumbnails(@PathVariable int width, @PathVariable int height, @PathVariable int limit) throws HeightNotAllowedException {
    if (height < 10) {
        throw new HeightNotAllowedException();
    }
    List<String> list = thumbnailService.processImages(width,height,limit);
    return new ThumbnailResponse(list.size(),list);
}
```

Global exception handler (though you can go for per controller one)

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = HeightNotAllowedException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "Invalid Height")
    public String heightError(HeightNotAllowedException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Invalid height");
        return "Invalid Height";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there are couple of ways, for this case you can do just like below.

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value="{width}/{height}/{limit}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity createThumbnails(@PathVariable int width, @PathVariable int height, @PathVariable int limit) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    if(width <10 || height <10){
       return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    List<String> list = thumbnailService.processImages(width,height,limit);
    ThumbnailResponse response = new ThumbnailResponse(list.size(),list);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(gson.toJson(response), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

However the standard way is to write Validator for the object and there is a method validate,Inside which you can write your validation logic and

```
class YourValidator implements Validator{
      public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
         //write your validation logic

      }
 }
```

and from your controller you can use it and validate the response like below.

```
if(error.hasErrors()){
   return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems interesting, but Master Slave has a solution which follow better Spring MVC. Thank you, I'm sure it can help!