# Custom Exception Handling/Error Handling in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My Application  - **Java 1.6, Spring 3.1.2, Hibernate 4.1.1, Thymeleaf 2.0.15**
Currently in my application, there is no any `exception/error` handling mechanism is implemented. I handling exceptions in ordinary cultural way. But now I need to introduce a `"Robust Error Handling Mechanism"`. Please suggest me to implement Custom Error/Exception Handling mechanism with Example.

Thanks and appriciate from experts like you.

Comment: You should consider global error handling using @ControllerAdvice check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578889/spring-mvc-webservice-input-control-validator/26583704#26583704

Comment: But I need to implement some Generalized Custom Exception so that same Exception could be thrown acrross the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make as an answer its easier to format. When you say "But I need to implement some Generalized Custom Exception so that same Exception could be thrown acrross the application." Its how I understood it and something that *@ControllerAdvice* is directly handling, but it applies only to Controllers. Than again, all you lower layers can declare *throws* on the method, and delegate it to Controller for exception handling. As an example, the following would be the error handling controller handling your custom exception

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = VermaException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String heightError(VermaException ex) {
        return "error";
    }

}
```

Your exception

```
public class VermaException extends Exception {
}
```

now whenever the the exception is thrown from the controller class, it will be captured and handled in your *GlobalErrorHandler*.

Again pasting the reference http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

UPDATE after comment

*@ControllerAdvice* is added in the version 3.2, for the earlier version you can have a CommonController extended by your controller, containing the error handler methods e.g. per Controller solution

```
@Controller
public class CommonController {

    @ExceptionHandler
    public @ResponseBody String handle(VermaException e) {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

an extending contorller

```
@Controller
public class ExceptionController extends CommonController {

    @RequestMapping("/exception")
    public @ResponseBody String exception() {
        throw new VermaException();
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using Spring 3.1.2 and it seems does not have @ControllerAdvice annotation

Comment: I've updated an answer with a possible solution. There's a lot of improvement released with 3.2 version, especially with regard to support for testing, so if you're able, try to upgrade.

Comment: I have Inherited my Controller from CommonController where ExceptionHandlers are written but while throwing exceptions from Controller, Controller is not invoking ExceptionHandlers in CommonController.

Comment: not sure what are the issues you're facing, I've added a simple working example. You should be able to copy/paste and test